# How do I post an image with Nodejs and Multer?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am trying to build an application that consists of uploading a file(such as an image) and posting it.

this is what I have done so far:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/img');
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb){
        cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now());
      }
    });

var upload = multer({storage: storage});
```

So this code above will save the files I upload them in a folder called 'img'

```
module.exports = function(app){

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render('index');
    });

    app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function(req, res){

    res.send(req.file);
    });
}
```

Now in the last post request I get all the metadata information about the file in 'req.file'. I wanted to get the file and post it if someone, for instance, makes this request:

```
app.get('/postedfiles', function(req, res){});
```

should I save them in a database or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, it saves inside your computer, inside the directory that you choose.

This is the plain html form for the multer upload.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/profile" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="avatar" value="">
      <input type="submit" name="" value="ssss">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is our backend code. Inside storage, I choose where  to upload the files, which is under `/upload` directory, and give them file names of that current time. We declare out `upload` variable for set up, and then we use `upload.single('avatar')` while we're getting a post request, we declare it right before the callback. What `avatar` here is that it's the file name from out html form inside **input** tag. And in the callback we can get to our file by using `req.file`. The module saves the file this way, very easy to use.

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var app = express()

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, __dirname + '/uploads')      //you tell where to upload the files,
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.png')
  }
})

var upload = multer({storage: storage,
    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
      console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
    },
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){    
    res.render('mult');  //our html document
})

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  console.log(req.file);
  return false;
})
```

Make sure, you give the images and extension of either png or jpeg, or whatever you want to use, otherwise it will not be considered as an image in the computer.

**Update on your question**

If you want to show the client the image without refreshing  the page, just use AJAX with a get request on the client browser. You can upload the files inside your *web server* or to *a web server* and retrieve images from there. For example, my profile picture in stackoverflow is saved  [here](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e95c843bcbea716f1a637e3412a4eca2?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1)

You can use params in a get request to receive all the files from server.

For example, imagine a client making a get request to `/uploads/imageOfApet.png`.

```
app.get('/uploads/:theImageName', function(req, res){
   console.log(req.params.theImageName); //returns the imageOfApet.png
   var theName = req.params.theImageName; //imageOfApet.png
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/uploads/" + theName); //Sending the user the file
})
```

Comment: I understood that. Thank you for your answer by the way. But what I want is to be able to show the user, right on the webpage, the image I just uploaded. And I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: For example in this piece of code files are saved to `uploads` directory, i can just link the images to my website inside like www.mywebsite.com/uploads/imageNumberOne.png

Comment: Thank you so much. I would very appreciate if you can give me some code example so I can understand how it's done. Im sorry, Im still a beginner on this matter.

Comment: Do you know how to use parameteres in nodejs @JeffGoes Thank you too !

Comment: You can also use queries, but params are more convenient

Comment: Hope I was enough help, please see the update @JeffGoes

Comment: thank you! it helped me a lot. Do you have any contact where I can reach you if I get into any issues?

Comment: please check my answer on the other question, ajax is not used to retrieve the img bytes. it is used to retrieve if there's any update/message for the user. @JeffGoes all you have to do is using img tags to retrieve the images, after you have set an `app.get` with `res.sendFile` method. Please check my answer